# Unable to enable AWS Amplify Admin UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm currently finding myself unable to enable the Admin UI. It was enabled before and now does not seem to work.

When I looked at my backends I see this.

[Image of Amplify backend environment with a button to enable admin UI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAOnH.png)

I then clicked the switch to turn on the Admin UI as shown below.

[Image of the Admin UI enable screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxIkx.png)

I clicked it and it says it's enabling in a [popup here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esD8q.png), before saying it succeeded in another [popup here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJOWs.png).

I thought this was originally something wrong with my project but it's happening on my other amplify project - is the Amplify Admin UI down for some reason?

P.S. I was going to post this on server fault as [this post says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stack-exchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws) but there was no tag for Amplify on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved as shown in this ticket I opened.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-adminui/issues/206

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not an answer, I cannot make comment so I have to write here.

I wasted a whole day by meeting the exactly the same issue.

At the same time, I tried to run Amplify pull --appid --envName several times, it always stuck there.

Amazon status [page](https://status.aws.amazon.com) shows everything is fine now but I cannot believe it.

I also posted a [question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=340406) here  but it seems nobody answered it.

I hope this issue was discovered by more people and Amazon finally can fix it, I believe it's not a problem on our side.

Comment: It works after github issues was fixed. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1829

Comment: Yes it was resolved quite quickly thankfully - I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the environment and then clicking Open Admin UI?

[image: 1]

I also wasnt able to login clicking in the URL and with my credentials, but clicking there worked.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it was a temporary issue that AWS resolved on the first day, it is covered in the accepted answer I posted